# How to calculate difference between two dates in months in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date

I have two columns in a MySQL table:

- DateOfService (datetime)
- BirthDate (date)

I want to run a MySQL query that will provide date difference between these two fields in months.

How can I do this in a MySQL select query?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of what output you expect? E.g.: today is April 12th and my birthday is April 14th or May 12th or May 15th. What values would you expect to receive from the query?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288984/the-difference-in-months-between-dates-in-mysql

Comment: DateOfService column date will always be greater then BirthDate column. So I need to subtract BirthDate from DateOfService and calculate the difference in months.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This could work:

```
SELECT 12 * (YEAR(DateOfService) 
              - YEAR(BirthDate)) 
       + (MONTH(DateOfService) 
           - MONTH(BirthDate)) AS months 
FROM table
```

Comment: i have used this query..issue arises particular date. the dates are 2014-01-30 to 2014-03-02 differs 30days only.but it is returns 2 months difference.

Answer (score 50):

Have a look at the [***TIMESTAMPDIFF()***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function in MySQL.

What this allows you to do is pass in two `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` values (or even `DATE` as MySQL will auto-convert) as well as the unit of time you want to base your difference on.

You can specify `MONTH` as the unit in the first parameter:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, '2012-05-05', '2012-06-04')
-- 0
```

---

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, '2012-05-05', '2012-06-05')
-- 1
```

---

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, '2012-05-05', '2012-06-15')
-- 1
```

---

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, '2012-05-05', '2012-12-16')
-- 7
```

It basically gets the number of months elapsed from the first date in the parameter list. This solution accounts for the varying amount of days in each month (28,30,31) as well as leap years.

---

If you want decimal precision in the number of months elapsed, it's a little more complicated, but here is how you can do it:

```
SELECT 
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, startdate, enddate) +
  DATEDIFF(
    enddate,
    startdate + INTERVAL
      TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, startdate, enddate)
    MONTH
  ) /
  DATEDIFF(
    startdate + INTERVAL
      TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, startdate, enddate) + 1
    MONTH,
    startdate + INTERVAL
      TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, startdate, enddate)
    MONTH
  )
```

Where `startdate` and `enddate` are your date parameters, whether it be from two date columns in a table or as input parameters from a script:

Examples:

```
With startdate = '2012-05-05' AND enddate = '2012-05-27':
-- Outputs: 0.7097
```

---

```
With startdate = '2012-05-05' AND enddate = '2012-06-13':
-- Outputs: 1.2667
```

---

```
With startdate = '2012-02-27' AND enddate = '2012-06-02':
-- Outputs: 3.1935
```

Comment: Hey i am able to achieve above result but my condition is that i need 0.5 year , 1 year, 1.5 year, 2 year ,2.5 year and so on.. how could i do that!!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

`SELECT DATEDIFF(DateOfService, BirthDate) / 30 as months FROM ...`

Answer (score 3):

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, Start_date, End_date)
```

Example:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, BirthDate, DateOfService) AS Months FROM Table
```

Answer (score 3):

The 'right' answer depends on exactly what you need. I like to *round to the closest whole number*.

Consider these examples:
1st January -> 31st January: It's 0 whole months, and almost 1 month long.
1st January -> 1st February? It's 1 whole month, and exactly 1 month long.

To get the number of **whole** months, use:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, '2018-01-01', '2018-01-31');  => 0
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, '2018-01-01', '2018-02-01');  => 1
```

To get a **rounded** duration in months, you could use:

```
SELECT ROUND(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, '2018-01-01', '2018-01-31')*12/365.24); => 1
SELECT ROUND(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, '2018-01-01', '2018-01-31')*12/365.24); => 1
```

This is accurate to +/- 5 days and for ranges over 1000 years. Zane's answer is obviously more accurate, but it's too verbose for my liking.

Answer (score 2):

TRY with

> PERIOD_DIFF(P1,P2)

Returns the number of months between periods P1 and P2. P1 and P2 should be in the format `YYMM` or `YYYYMM`. Note that the period arguments P1 and P2 are not date values.

> mysql> SELECT PERIOD_DIFF(200802,200703);
>           -> 11

Comment: this does not answer the OP question as it does not accept datetime format or even date format. Maybe if this question was edited showing this then I might retract my -1.

Answer (score 2):

Based on a summary of all answers and a Google search, I think there are four almost similar ways to write it:

1)

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, Start_date, End_date) AS Period
```

E.g.

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, MIN(r.rental_date), MAX(r.rental_date)) AS Period
```

2)

```
PERIOD_DIFF(date_format(now(), '%Y%m'), date_format(time, '%Y%m')) as months
```

Or

```
PERIOD_DIFF(date_format(End_date(), '%Y%m'), date_format(Start_date, '%Y%m')) as months
```

E.g.

```
PERIOD_DIFF(date_format(MAX(r.rental_date), '%Y%m'), date_format(MIN(r.rental_date), '%Y%m')) as months
```

3)

```
PERIOD_DIFF(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM NOW()), EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM time)) AS months
```

OR

```
PERIOD_DIFF(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM End_date()), EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM Start_date)) AS months
```

E.g.

```
PERIOD_DIFF(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM MAX(r.rental_date)), EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM MIN(r.rental_date))) as Months
```

4)

```
PERIOD_DIFF(concat(year(d1),if(month(d1)<10,'0',''),month(d1)), concat(year(d2),if(month(d2)<10,'0',''),month(d2))) as Months**
```

E.g.

```
PERIOD_DIFF(
            concat(year(MAX(r.rental_date)),if(month(MAX(r.rental_date))<10,'0',''),month(MAX(r.rental_date))),
            concat(year(MIN(r.rental_date)),if(month(MIN(r.rental_date))<10,'0',''),month(MIN(r.rental_date)))
           ) as Months
```