# MySQL: date difference in months (even if 'month' < 30 days should be count as 1)

Tags: mysql, sql, datediff

I would like to compare 2 dates: '2012-05-05', '2012-06-04' and receive 1 as a result (difference bettwen May and June).

What I got:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, '2012-05-05', '2012-06-04') as difference
-- output: 0
```

I'm looking for a query for which I will receive **1** as a result (dates are from 2 different months; not important if difference is in fact < 30 days).

I've tried:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, DATE_FORMAT('2012-05-05','%Y-%m'), DATE_FORMAT('2012-06-04','%Y-%m') ) as difference
-- output: NULL
```

also:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF( DATE_FORMAT('2012-05-05','%Y-%m'), DATE_FORMAT('2012-06-04','%Y-%m') ) as difference
-- output: NULL
```

Do you have other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there are ways of doing it with the function, but you can do simple case... Obviously can be improved.

```
CASE
 WHEN DAYS <=30 THEN 1
 WHEN DAYS BETWEEN 31 and 60 THEN 2
 --ELSE ....
END as MONTH_DIFF
```

Also found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633821/how-to-calculate-difference-between-two-dates-in-months-in-mysql):

```
SELECT 12 * (YEAR(DateOfService) 
              - YEAR(BirthDate)) 
       + (MONTH(DateOfService) 
           - MONTH(BirthDate)) AS months 
FROM table
```

Comment: 1. Won't work (7 days can give result 0 or 1 depending on "real" month):
`SELECT 
CASE
 WHEN DATEDIFF('2012-02-05', '2012-02-06') <=30 THEN 1
END as MONTH_DIFF
-- Output: 1; Expected output: 0`

2. That's AWESOME! Thank's :)

Answer (score 2):

In mysql documentation has function PERIOD_DIFF that returns the number of months between periods P1 and P2. P1 and P2 should be in the format YYMM or YYYYMM.

```sql
SELECT PERIOD_DIFF('201205', '201206') as difference
```

If you from datetime value, use DATE_FORMAT. Such as :

```sql
SELECT PERIOD_DIFF(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m'),DATE_FORMAT(YOURCOLUMN, '%Y%m')) AS difference 
FROM YOURTABLE;
```