# how to take the month difference of two dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql

how to take the month difference of two dates in MySQL.

I m trying to get the month difference of two dates but I'm getting no. of days.

```
select datediff('2014-10-17T00:00:00.000-07:00', '2015-02-06T00:00:00.000-08:00');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate difference between two dates in months in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633821/how-to-calculate-difference-between-two-dates-in-months-in-mysql)

Comment: Try this `Select PERIOD_DIFF(MONTH(date1),MONTH(date2)) from table;`

Comment: @GauravGenius PERIOD_DIFF should be in format %Y%m not month only

Comment: @Gaj, right thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @RaviRanjan Please accept the answer which helped you most in solving your problem. It helps future readers. If the answers weren't helpful leave comments below them. So the poster can update them accordingly.

Answer (score 13):

## [TIMESTAMPDIFF()](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timestampdiff-function.php)

is your solution.

---

Syntax would be

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(unit, datetime_expr1, datetime_expr2);
```

---

> Returns `datetime_expr2 − datetime_expr1`, where `datetime_expr1` and `datetime_expr2` are date or datetime expressions. One expression may be a date and the other a datetime; a date value is treated as a datetime having the time part '00:00:00' where necessary.
>
> <sub>[~MySQL :: MySQL 5.5 Reference Manual :: 12.7 Date and Time Functions~](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)</sub>

Legal values for `unit`

- MICROSECOND (microseconds)
- SECOND
- MINUTE
- HOUR
- DAY
- WEEK
- MONTH
- QUARTER
- YEAR

---

Examples

```
mysql> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,'2003-02-01','2003-05-01');
        -> 3
mysql> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,'2002-05-01','2001-01-01');
        -> -1
mysql> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,'2003-02-01','2003-05-01 12:05:55');
        -> 128885
```

Answer (score 3):

Please use this code

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, '2014-10-17T00:00:00.000-07:00','2015-02-06T00:00:00.000-08:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

This could help,

```
SELECT 12 * (YEAR(STR_TO_DATE('01/01/2011', '%d/%m/%Y')) - 
YEAR(STR_TO_DATE('01/01/2010', '%d/%m/%Y'))) 
+ (MONTH(STR_TO_DATE('01/01/2011', '%d/%m/%Y')) 
- MONTH(STR_TO_DATE('01/01/2010', '%d/%m/%Y'))) AS months
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select PERIOD_DIFF(Date_format('2015-02-06T00:00:00.000-08:00', '%Y-%m'), Date_format('2014-10-17T00:00:00.000-07:00', '%Y%m'))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
in MySQL server 
DATEDIFF is built in function
You can get Difference of 
Day
Month
Year

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,'2018-05-01',GetDate())
SELECT DATEDIFF(Month,'2018-05-01',GetDate())
SELECT DATEDIFF(Year,'2018-05-01',GetDate())
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.

Comment: MySql DateDiff does not support this syntax. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff