# mysql difference in month as column in where clause

Tags: mysql, date, period

need your help. I tried myself but cant solve it.

I have a table with date column (ex. birth) So i need to select all rows where birth is in past more than one months.

I googled and found a SO question similar
[The difference in months between dates in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288984/the-difference-in-months-between-dates-in-mysql)

But there is no a condition by this new period. My wrong query is:

```
select id,period_diff(date_format(now(), "%Y%m"), date_format(birth, "%Y%m")) as months 
from t1
where months>0 
limit 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Below:

use `having` (`ALIAS` months in `WHERE` Clause not working here)

```
select id,period_diff(date_format(now(), "%Y%m"), date_format(birth, "%Y%m")) as months 
from t1
having months>0 
limit 10
```

`HAVING` is like `WHERE` but it is able to work on columns which are computed (`Alias`). `HAVING` works by pruning results after the rest of the query has been run - it is not a substitute for the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2):

you cannot use `ALIAS` in WHERE Clause

```
SELECT id,
       period_diff(date_format(now(), "%Y%m"), date_format(birth, "%Y%m")) as months 
FROM   t1
WHERE period_diff(date_format(now(), "%Y%m"), date_format(birth, "%Y%m")) > 0 
LIMIT 10
```