# How To Get The Difference of a Two Date Value in MySQL and the result is in month wise?

Tags: php, mysql

Here I Have The Two Dates Like The Following

```
2012-08-12 to 2012-10-20
```

I Need The Output Like the following:

```
month[08]=19
month[09]=30
month[10]=20
```

You Can Solve it By PHP,MYSQL

Comment: I don't understand what your output represents.  Are you trying to get the number of days within each month in the range that fall between the given days?

Comment: i tried to using date_diff in php but i can't get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`PERIOD_DIFF(P1,P2)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_period-diff) to get the number of months between two dates.

> Returns the number of months between periods P1 and P2. P1 and P2
>   should be in the format YYMM or YYYYMM. Note that the period arguments
>   P1 and P2 are not date values.
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT PERIOD_DIFF(200802,200703);
>         -> 11
> ```

In your case, you would use:

```
SELECT PERIOD_DIFF(DATE_FORMAT('2012-10-20', '%Y%m'), DATE_FORMAT('2012-08-12', '%Y%m'))
```

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5159675/679449), using `EXTRACT` may be faster:

> ```
> SELECT
>     PERIOD_DIFF(
>         EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM '2012-10-20'), 
>         EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM '2012-08-12')) AS months 
> FROM your_table;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to build a table in MySQL that contained all the possible date values in the date ranges you are interested in you could do this from a query relatively easily.

The table would simply need to have a single column like

```
dates
----------
2012-01-01
2012-01-02
...
2050-12-31
```

Then you could query the table like this:

```
SELECT YEAR(`dates`) as `years`, MONTH(`dates`) as `months`, COUNT(`dates`) as `days`
FROM date_table
WHERE `dates` BETWEEN 'YYYY-MM-DD' AND 'YYYY-MM-DD'
GROUP BY `years`, `months`
ORDER BY `years` ASC, `months` ASC
```

This sort of approach of having a table of dates is commonly used in BI/Data Warehousing applications, but I think it could work here for you.

Note that I added a "years" value in there as well, as I imagine this is something you would need to deal with as well, unless you didn't ever plan to have date ranges that could span across years.