# Date difference using months

Tags: mysql, datediff

I have month names in my database, for eg. `tomonth` and `frommonth`. The data stored is like 'JAN', 'FEB' etc.

What do I have to do to get difference between `tomonth`  and `frommonth`?

Comment: How do you know which year? Does it matter? Have you considered storing dates as dates? How do you want the "difference" rendered? The number of months?

Comment: PERIOD_DIFF calculates months between two dates.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288984/the-difference-in-months-between-dates-in-mysql

Comment: @DavidKarlsson:PERIOD_DIFF  calculates months between period. he is storing as string.

Comment: I completely agree with @Ben's comment, above.  However, if you genuinely want to record solely the month and not a particular month/year or date, why not store the month as an integer (1=Jan, 12=Dec)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your could use STR_TO_DATE:

```
SELECT
  MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(tomonth,'%b'))-MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(frommonth,'%b')) as montdiff
FROM
  yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below query

```
select (tomonth-frommonth) as monthdiff from
( SELECT case when `frommonth` = 'Jan' then 1 
   when frommonth = 'Feb' then 2  
   when frommonth = 'Mar' then 3 
   when frommonth = 'Apr' then 4  
   when frommonth = 'May' then 5  
   when frommonth = 'Jun' then 6  
   when frommonth = 'Jul' then 7  
   when frommonth = 'Aug' then 8  
   when frommonth = 'Sep' then 9  
   when frommonth = 'Oct' then 10  
   when frommonth = 'Nov' then 11  
   when frommonth = 'Dec' then 12 
   end frommonth, 
( case when tomonth = 'Jan' then 1
   when tomonth = 'Feb' then 2  
   when tomonth = 'Mar' then 3 
   when tomonth = 'Apr' then 4  
   when tomonth = 'May' then 5  
   when tomonth = 'Jun' then 6  
   when tomonth = 'Jul' then 7  
   when tomonth = 'Aug' then 8  
   when tomonth = 'Sep' then 9  
   when tomonth = 'Oct' then 10  
   when tomonth = 'Nov' then 11  
   when tomonth = 'Dec' then 12 
   end ) as tomonth from table) a
```