# mysql select people older than 3 months and younger than

Tags: mysql

I have mysql table people with row "born".
In born I have

```
born
----
2013-07-15
2010-11-29
2013-11-01
```

etc.
How can I make mysql query to select people older than 3 months so it should compare row "born"? in this case it should return first and second item.

And how to select people younger than 4 years? in this case it should return all items.
I would like to port it so select older/younger than day, x days, month, months, year, years etc.

many thanks

Comment: Asked and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288984/the-difference-in-months-between-dates-in-mysql  you may have to use datediff if you want months.

Answer (score 7):

This isn't exactly correct, because it won't account for birthdays, but should give you the basic idea:

older than 3 months:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE born < (now() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```

younger than 4 years:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE born > (now() - INTERVAL 4 YEAR)
```