# Is there any method in mysql which return the difference between two dates in months and days

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Is there any method in mysql database which return the difference between two dates in months and days. for eg if i provide 01-01-2018 as fromdate and 02-02-2018 as todate i want to get the result as 1 month 1 day.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288984/the-difference-in-months-between-dates-in-mysql

Comment: i want month as well as day. Not month alone. the link u provided talks only about month. i want to have both in one result.

Comment: then put `DAY` or `DAYOFMONTH` instead of `MONTH`; and if you want both, just put one with `MONTH` and put another one with `DAYOFMONTH` :)

Comment: i want the difference between two dates in month and day. if i give 01-01-2018 as fromDate and 02-02-2018 as toDate i want to get the output as 1 month 1 day. Is there any method like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF('2018-02-01', '2018-01-01')/30) AS months, DATEDIFF('2018-02-01', '2018-01-01')%30 AS days;
```

The only problem is that is calculates months as 30 days. So it doesn't take into account how many days the current month is.

**UPDATE:**

**A solution for taking month length into account**

```
SELECT 
(CASE WHEN (DAY('2018-02-02') >= DAY('2018-01-01')) 
THEN
    (YEAR('2018-02-02')*12 + MONTH('2018-02-02')) - (YEAR('2018-01-01')*12 + MONTH('2018-01-01'))
ELSE
    (YEAR('2018-02-02')*12 + MONTH('2018-02-02')) - (YEAR('2018-01-01')*12 + MONTH('2018-01-01')) - 1
END) AS months,
(CASE WHEN (DAY('2018-02-02') >= DAY('2018-01-01')) 
THEN
    DAY('2018-02-02') - DAY('2018-01-01')
ELSE
    (DAY(LAST_DAY('2018-01-01')) - DAY('2018-01-01')) + DAY('2018-02-02')
END) AS days;
```

*You should insert the dates as a variable (replace '2018-01-01' with `fromdate` and '2018-02-02' with `todate`).*

**Explanation:**

It has 2 cases for both months and days:

- **Case 1**: *the day of the month of `todate` is higher than (or equal to) the date of the month of `fromdate`*. In this case the number of months is the number of years * 12 + the number of months of `todate`, minus the same calculation for `fromdate`. The number of days is simply the day number of `todate` minus the day number of `fromdate`.
- **Case 2**: *the day of the month of `todate` is lower than the date of the month of `fromdate`*. In this case the number of months is the number of years * 12 + the number of months of `todate`, minus the same calculation for `fromdate`, minus 1 (because the month isn't 'full'). The number of days is the last day of the month of `fromdate`, minus the day of `fromdate`, plus the day of the month of `todate`. Or in other words: the amount of days passed in the month of `fromdate` since the day of that month, plus the days passed in the month of `todate`.

Comment: can we select based on no f days in a month as well.?

Comment: Updated my answer, felt like solving this puzzle :-) let me know if it does everything you need!