# How to calculate difference between two timestamps and then group by month for charting purposes in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to form a SQL statement that meets the following criteria based on records that have date/timestamps and various other varchar and int fields.

- Calculate the difference between two fields named `time_depart` and `time_return` in decimal hours
- Total up the differences and group by month up to the last 12 months.
- Separate totals based on `event_type`

Example Data Set

table `events`:

```
id | time_depart         | time_return         | event_type  | summary
--------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 2019-02-11 10:00:00 | 2019-02-11 10:30:00 | 1           | test summary
2  | 2019-02-11 10:30:00 | 2019-02-11 11:30:00 | 1           | some more data
3  | 2019-02-11 11:00:00 | 2019-02-11 12:30:00 | 2           | even more data
4  | 2019-02-11 11:30:00 | 2019-02-11 13:30:00 | 2           | just a summary
5  | 2019-02-11 12:00:00 | 2019-02-11 14:30:00 | 2           | again more
......
```

Would like a return similar to where `event_type = 1` is `'training'` and `event_type = 2` is a `'mission'`

```
month     | trainingTime | missionTime  
--------------------------------------------------------------
january   | 15.25        | 22 
february  | 20           | 25
march     | 10.5         | 35.5
april     | 52           | 20 
may       | 64           | 72 
june      | 100          | 10.75 
july      | 45           | 0 
august    | 26           | 15
september | 10.5         | 65
october   | 55           | 8
november  | 44           | 12.25 
december  | 17           | 0
```

Comment: As it is, your question is quite broad and not likely to get an accurate answer. To improve it, would you please provide sample data and expected output?

Comment: Was in the process of that, apologies, updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical solution is to use *conditional aggregation*. Group data by month, then compute separatly the sum of each event type.

It is unclear in which format you expect the durations to be expressed. The following query will return durations in seconds (you can then format them in your application layer or using MySQL date and time functions).

Query:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(time_depart, '%Y-%M') eventMonth,
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN event_type = 1 
        THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, time_depart, time_return)
        ELSE 0 
    END) trainingTime,
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN event_type = 2 
        THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, time_depart, time_return)
        ELSE 0 
    END) missionTime
FROM events
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(time_depart, '%Y-%M')
ORDER BY eventMonth
```

NB: it is probably a good idea to use the year as a grouping condition too, in case your data spreads over more than 12 months.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/87iK3sioSopjG32CRs8HUN/0)** with your sample data:

```
| eventMonth    | trainingTime | missionTime |
| ------------- | ------------ | ----------- |
| 2019-February | 5400         | 21600       |
```

Comment: Perfect, I may just leave this as seconds and then use javascript on the frontend to manipulate to decimal hours.  I tried changing the TIMESTAMPDIFF to HOUR instead but it would give whole hours instead.

Comment: On closer inspection I am seeing a bit of a discrepencie where the seconds don't seem to be calculated correctly.  For a one hour difference in time I'm getting a result of 10000

Comment: @Huttser: yes I think you are right, the usage of `SEC_TO_TIME()` was not relevant, I removed it. Should return the correct results now.

Comment: Figured it out, I had a previous version of your code that had sec_to_time and this was skewing the numbers. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I have just searched this on another link:

`SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, time_depart, time_return) as difference;`

I hope this helped...
link: [The difference in months between dates in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288984/the-difference-in-months-between-dates-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Easy enough.

```
SELECT
MONTH(time_return) as month,
SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, time_depart, time_return)) as sum_diff_in_seconds,
TIME_FORMAT(SUM(SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, time_depart, time_return))), '%H:%s:%s') as sum_time
FROM
<your table>
GROUP BY MONTH(time_return)
```

You can modify the group by to your needs.

There is one issue with the TIME_FORMAT, it will only allow a formatting up to '838:59:59', which is the max value the TIME Datatype can have.

The number of seconds should be accurate...

One last thing: you'll probably have "edge" values, where depart and return are not from the same month... they're counted according to the "group by" to either the month of depart or the month of return.

second edit: you modified the post and added a third requirement.. add it to GROUP BY like

```
GROUP BY MONTH(..), type
```

HtH