# The DATEDIFF() function problem regarding the result returning in months

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQl Server. The problem is whenever i  using

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(year, '2017/08/25', '2011/08/25') AS DateDiff`;
```

Statement an error is showing which goes as

> ERROR 1582 (42000): Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'.

The `DATEDIFF()` when i am trying to find the diff in months or year basically other than days is not working as it should.

however if i use `SELECT DATEDIFF('2017/08/25', '2011/08/25') AS DateDiff`;
its returning the value in days.

Comment: MySQL date format is **yyyy-mm-dd** not **yyyy/mm/dd**

Comment: @madhurbhaiya plainly, you're mistaken

Comment: @Strawberry I know that MySQL does allow different formats for date/datetime types, and tries to auto-interpret non-standard format; but it recommends against using non-standard format: "It is expected that you supply valid values. Unpredictable results may occur if you use values in other formats." Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-types.html

Comment: Nevertheless, that isn't the cause of the issue at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the **SQL Server** syntax for [`DATEDIFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
DATEDIFF(datepart, startdate, enddate)
```

which can return the difference in years, months, days etc.
In **MySql** the syntax of [`DATEDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) is different:

```
DATEDIFF(date1, date2)
```

and returns the difference `date1 - date2` in days.
You can use [`TIMESTAMPDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) which returns the difference `datetime_expr2 - datetime_expr1` in years, months, days etc as an integer:

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(unit, datetime_expr1, datetime_expr2)
```

like this:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(year, '2011/08/25', '2017/08/25') AS DateDiff;
```

result:

```
6
```

Answer (score 2):

Datediff returns days, not years. For an approximation divide the result by 365.25.

Alternatively, take a look at [How to get the difference in years from two different dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749639/how-to-get-the-difference-in-years-from-two-different-dates) if you're after an integer number of years or [The difference in months between dates in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288984/the-difference-in-months-between-dates-in-mysql) in the second answer for advice on timestampdiff and fractional months- apply the technique to years or divide that technique by 12