# how to solve every derived table must have it's own alias?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this sql query

```
Select parent_order_id,product_id,hub_id,cast(1- '0.05' * MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE(), order_processing_date)as unsigned) AS total_sum 
      FROM (select q1.parent_order_id, q1.product_id, q1.hub_id, q1.order_processing_date from (select o1.parent_order_id, 
            o2.product_id, o1.hub_id, o1.order_processing_date from licious.orders as o1 join licious.order_items as o2 on o1.order_id = o2.order_id 
            WHERE DATE(o1.order_processing_date) BETWEEN DATE(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 90 day) )AND DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) 
            AND  o1.status = "Delivered") as q1 
        join ((select o1.parent_order_id from licious.orders as o1 join licious.order_items as o2 on o1.order_id = o2.order_id 
              WHERE DATE(o1.order_processing_date) BETWEEN DATE(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 90 day) )
              AND DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) AND  o1.status = "Delivered" group by parent_order_id having count(parent_order_id > 1)
              )) as q2 on q1.parent_order_id = q2.parent_order_id)
            group by 
              parent_order_id, 
              product_id, 
              hub_id, 
              order_processing_date 
            order by 
              parent_order_id desc, 
              total_sum desc;
```

I'm getting error every derived table must have it's own alias
I know i need to use alias but i have already used it and i don't know where to modify my query
Can anyone just check the whole query and update it. It will be a great help.

Ps: I just edited my question because the previous one got solved just by writing UNSIGNED instead of int

Comment: I get a different error on SET o1.status = "Delivered".

Comment: Actually because when i paste it in any sql beautifier , it gives error on SET o1.status = "Delivered" but when i try to execute it on sql workbench it gives me on the select statement

Comment: I just can't figure out the right solution

Comment: SET is not valid here and 'i'm just can't figure out the right solution' - you haven't described what you are seeking a solution to  only a problem with your solution.

Comment: okay so you are saying instead of SET o1.status = "Delivered"  i should write  o1.status = "Delivered"

Comment: Try it and see..

Comment: I tried but still the error persists

Comment: You use the set statement twice. You probably followed a tutorial for a different database product.

Comment: I removed the set statement now and wrote o1.status = "Delivered"  . But the error still persists

Comment: There seem to be too many parenteses around q2.

Comment: But all of are of use and I rechecked it.

Comment: months_between is an oracle function and does not exist in mysql - you may be following an oracle tutorial but using mysql - that won't work there are many differences between oracle and mysql. If you want to learn oracle then it's also free , but a bit of a nuisance to install OR you may already have oracle and not tagged the question correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide an alias to the outer query:

```
Select parent_order_id,product_id,hub_id,cast(1- '0.05' * DATEDIFF(MONTH, SYSDATE(), order_processing_date)as unsigned) AS total_sum 
FROM (select q1.parent_order_id, q1.product_id, q1.hub_id, q1.order_processing_date from (select o1.parent_order_id, 
    o2.product_id, o1.hub_id, o1.order_processing_date from licious.orders as o1 join licious.order_items as o2 on o1.order_id = o2.order_id 
    WHERE DATE(o1.order_processing_date) BETWEEN DATE(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 90 day) )AND DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) 
    AND  o1.status = "Delivered") as q1 
join ((select o1.parent_order_id from licious.orders as o1 join licious.order_items as o2 on o1.order_id = o2.order_id 
      WHERE DATE(o1.order_processing_date) BETWEEN DATE(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 90 day) )
      AND DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) AND  o1.status = "Delivered" group by parent_order_id having count(parent_order_id > 1)
      )) as q2 on q1.parent_order_id = q2.parent_order_id) table1
    group by 
      parent_order_id, 
      product_id, 
      hub_id, 
      order_processing_date 
    order by 
      parent_order_id desc, 
      total_sum desc;
```

Comment: Thanks that got solved. But the query still didn't worked, throwing this error now FUNCTION licious.MONTHS_BETWEEN does not exist.

I have used moths_between to find the number of month between SYSDATE() and order_processing_date

Comment: You can use datediff for mysql instead of months_between https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288984/the-difference-in-months-between-dates-in-mysql

Comment: *You can use datediff for mysql instead of months_between* This is wrong - converting days to months is approximate. `TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, ...)` needed.

Comment: Thanks for the timestampdiff() it is running perfectly now.