# Calculate expiry date 3 months from now on MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have been given just the expiry dates for my loyalty cards, I need the query to display all the customers whose card will expire 3 months from the current systems date not hardcoded.

Lets say todays 2021-09-30, and the card expiry date for customer1 is 2021-12-12 and the customer2 is 2021-10-18. SO the query will display the name of the customer1 because its card is expiring in the 3rd month.

I have tried a few different methods but I can't seem to find a solution

> > select DISTINCT c.customername  from customers c  WHERE c.CardExpDate now() and
> > datediff(now(),c.CardExpDate) <= -2  order by c.customerID;

Comment: Possible duplicate: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288984/the-difference-in-months-between-dates-in-mysql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get difference between two dates in months using MySQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288984/how-to-get-difference-between-two-dates-in-months-using-mysql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
select c.*, timestampdiff(MONTH, now(3), CardExpDate) from customers c where
timestampdiff(MONTH, now(3), CardExpDate) = 3
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked like a charm. Got the answer I was looking for.